# How do I get an image assigned to a variable to show in a picture box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Please, why doesn't my image show in the picture box when I assign the path to a variable name in visual c#?
For example:

```
textBox1.Text = "\""+pictureBox1.FileName+"\"";
pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @textBox1.Text;
```

But it opens if I enter the path directly.

Comment: Did you try to debug and copy the path in textBox1.Text to compare to the path you enter directly?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @(textBox1.Text);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a relative path? If yes, make sure to check if the image is getting copied to the output directory. You do so by set the property as Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer.